# redundancy in laravel's templating engine?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade, laravel-5

From http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates :

(the controller)

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * The layout that should be used for responses.
     */
    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

    /**
     * Show the user profile.
     */
    public function showProfile()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('user.profile');
    }

}
```

(the template)

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('sidebar')


    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@stop

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@stop
```

Why does `layouts.master` need to be called twice? The fact that `$this->layout` needs to be set to `layouts.master` and the fact that you need to pass `layouts.master` to `@extends()` seems...  redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: You dont need to do that: http://laravel.io/forum/03-26-2014-passing-variables-to-blade-undefined-variable see responses by 'koomai'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's enough in your `showProfile()` method to put:

```
return View::make('user.profile');
```

instead of:

```
protected $layout = 'layouts.master';
```

and

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('user.profile');
```

**EDIT**

Another method when using `$layout` property is a bit more complicated.

In `layouts.master` template you don't use `yield('content')` but you put `{{ $content }}` as variable, so the file can look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  test

 {{ $content }}

  test2

{{ $sidebar }}

</body>
</html>
```

Now you can have property as before:

```
protected $layout = 'layouts.master';
```

and what you need is to set something to `content` and `sidebar` variables using:

```
$this->layout->content = 'this is content';
$this->layout->sidebar = 'this is sidebar';
```

layout will be displayed automatically

OF course in above 2 cases you can use use templates so you could use:

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('content');
$this->layout->sidebar = View::make('sidebar');
```

And have in those file defined content without `@section` for example:

**content.blade.php**

```
this is content
```

**sidebar.blade.php**

```
this is sidebar
```

Output for this will be:

```
test this is content test2 this is sidebar
```

This method for me it's much more complicated. I use always `return View::make('user.profile');` and have defined my template as you showed at the beginning (extending other template with `@section` to put there its own content)